# How to make sure get the same session

Tags: java, spring, jsp, session

Here is my part of code

Jsp :

```
<script src="../../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
            $("#submit").click( function(){
                    $('#pairingForm').attr('data-ajax','false');
                    $("#pairingForm").submit();
            });

    <form action = "pairing" id = "pairingForm">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "FromPairing" value = "Y">
        <%
            request.getSession().setAttribute("qoo", "qoo");
            // and I still tried to use this 
            //session.setAttribute("qoo","qoo");
        %>          
    </form>
```

Java:

```
@RequestMapping("/pairing")
public ModelAndView pairing(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    System.out.println(" FromPairing = " + request.getParameter("FromPairing"));
    // return Y here 
    System.out.println("qoo = " + session.getAttribute("qoo"));
    //return null here
}
```

When I use the IP to be domain name, it works find. But when it comes domain name, I will get different session id (found it in debug mode). Maybe because the server will redirect Http post to me(I am not sure), it will create a new session. So my question is how to make sure I can get the same session through redirect from another server except pass session in url?

Comment: Are you sure you want session variables here? It looks like you're trying to submit a form from a jsp to a form proessing servlet. Are you getting the same session id in both places?

Comment: I am sure I want session parameter in the java part. And I am sure I used the same id. Maybe the confusing part is I submit form to java, but that is I want post session and the other hidden parameter to java part in the same time. However, only the session part return null.